# Android - Get id of dynamically generated buttons

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I'm trying to implement a feature in my app where the user can add buttons to the screen and then delete them with a long press.

I was able to do the first part where the user can add the buttons and the user can delete the most recently added button. However if you try to delete any of the other buttons it gives a NullPointerException.

Here is my method which creates a new button:

```
    public Button makeButton(Context context, String label, final GestureDetector gdt, int buttonId) {



    btn = new Button(context);

    v = new TextView(context);
    v.setText("");
    v.setHeight(10);


    ScrollView s = (ScrollView) homeView.findViewById(R.id.mainScroll);
    s.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);

    btn.setText(label);
    btn.setWidth(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
    btn.setHeight(70);
    btn.setId(buttonId);
    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
    btn.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            id = btn.getId();

            gdt.onTouchEvent(event);



            switch(event.getAction()) {

            case(MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN):

                ColorDrawable color = (ColorDrawable) btn.getBackground();
                int backgroundColor = color.getColor();

                if(backgroundColor == Color.GREEN) {
                    btn.setBackgroundColor(Color.YELLOW);
                    showToast("Running late??");
                }

            }

            return true;

        }

    });




    Ll.addView(btn);
    Ll.addView(v);


    return btn;


}
```

Here is the onClickListener() for the button which is used to create new buttons:

```
    addButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            factory.inflate(R.layout.eventadd, null);
            final View addEvent = factory.inflate(R.layout.eventadd, null);
            final EditText eventTime = (EditText) addEvent.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
            AlertDialog.Builder createEvent = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);

            createEvent.setTitle("Add new event");
            createEvent.setView(addEvent);
            (createEvent).setPositiveButton("Add Event", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    String getTxt = eventTime.getText().toString();
                    makeButton(context, getTxt, gestureDetector, id);
                    id++;
                }



            });
            createEvent.show();

        }

    });
```

And finally this is my GestureListener:

```
    private class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {



    @Override
    public void onLongPress(MotionEvent event) {


        showToast("Button " + btn.getId() + " deleted");
        btn.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        ((LinearLayout)btn.getParent()).removeViewAt(id);
        ((LinearLayout)v.getParent()).removeView(v);
    }

}
```

I'm pretty sure the error is something to do with id's of the buttons and how they are deleted in the GestureListener. Of course I'm more than likely wrong.Thanks for all the help :)

Comment: where are you setting on your GestureListener to your button? how will the GestureListener always be referencing the correct v and id fields?

Comment: In the onTouch() of the makeButton method (gdt.onTouchEvent(event)); That was one of the things I thought could be the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is in your GestureListener.

You're doing `((LinearLayout)btn.getParent()).removeViewAt(id);`  This removes a view at a specific index.  I believe you want

`View view = ((LinearLayout)btn.getParent()).findViewById(id)` to return you a view, which you should then pass that view to

`((LinearLayout)btn.getParent()).removeView(view)`;

**EDIT**

It looks like you're keeping a private class variable for your `Button`.  This means that the button there will ALWAYS be the last button you made.  In your `onTouch()` method, you reference that `btn` variable, which is the last button you made.  If you change the first line in your `onTouch()` method to `id = v.getId()`, it should give you the right button.

Comment: @DanielScott What are you attaching the GestureListener to?

Comment: @DanielScott Something else I might recommend instead of using id's, would be to use the `setTag(Object obj)` method of a view.  This will let you tie an object to the view instead of an Id.  You could then pass, say a constant string as the tag, and later use `findViewByTag(Object obj)` to find the view based on the string.

Comment: Okay I will try using tags. One other question, what do you mean by what am I tying the GestureListener to? I'd probably understand if it was worded differently. Thanks for all your help :)

Comment: The tags don't seem to be the problem. After fiddling it a bit more I think it is because of something to do with the way I'm assigning the buttons onTouch because when multiple buttons are added, no matter where I touch the action takes place only on the last button added. Hopefully that helps :)

Comment: @DanielScott I'm just throwing this out there, but mind changing `id = btn.getId();` to `id = v.getId();`.  This will force you to get the Id of the touched view.  In the onTouch method, you're referencing the button that is outside the scope. I see it now I think.  I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Yes that worked!! Thank you for explaining so well, you helped me understand how it works as well! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

use a stack of buttons ids. 
when ever you create button, save its id in that stack 
and when you press delete button get the last present id from stack and remove button -> then remove its id from stack as well.

Comment: Yes I think there is a problem with the ids not being assigned to each button and saved there. However how would I fix this with the stack as the buttons can be deleted randomly?